# don't know where to use .map() so I can see all my json results

Tags: reactjs

I am using the randomperson API. 
I should get 5 random people, but with the code I wrote I only get one.

I tried typing `data.results[0].map()` and also `this.state.person.map()`....
but I says

> "TypeError: this.state.person.map is not a function".

```
import React from 'react';

class PersonInfo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        person: null,
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ person: data.results[0], loading: false })
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>loading...</div>;
        }

        if (!this.state.person) {
            return <div>didn't get a person</div>;
        }
        return (
          <div className="person-container">

            <div className="person-card">
              <div className="person-card-title">
                  <h4>{this.state.person.name.title} </h4>

                  <h4>{this.state.person.name.first} </h4> 
                  <h4>{this.state.person.name.last}</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="person-card-info">
                  <ul>
                      <li>adres: <span> {this.state.person.location.street}     </span> <span>{this.state.person.location.city}</span></li>
                  <li>phone: <span> {this.state.person.phone}</span></li>
                  <li>age: <span> {this.state.person.dob.age}</span></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <img src={this.state.person.picture.large} alt="person face" />
            </div>

        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PersonInfo;
```

I would like to have 1 person-container with 5 person-card elements.

Comment: set the state to an array, to store fetched data.

`state = {
        loading: true,
        person: [],
    };` and also remove `[0]` from `data.results`

Comment: `data.results[0]` will give you only once person. `data.results` will give you all 5 persons data

Comment: Hi, the result without the [0] does not work because the all the data is stored in objects in the first array. If you copy paste the url: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5 in your browser it will become more clear what I mean I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instaed of storing only 1 record in state like,

```
this.setState({person: data.results[0], loading: false})
```

you need to store all the records in state,

```
this.setState({person: data.results, loading: false})
```

Now you cna iterate over `this.state.person` to get all the records,

```
{
    this.state.person && this.state.person.length > 0 && this.state.person.map(person => {
        return  <div className="person-card" key={`${person.name.first}${person.name.last}`}>
                    <div className="person-card-title">
                        <h4>{person.name.title} </h4>

                        <h4>{person.name.first} </h4> 
                        <h4>{person.name.last}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="person-card-info">
                        <ul>
                            <li>adres: <span> {person.location.street}     </span> <span>{person.location.city}</span></li>
                        <li>phone: <span> {person.phone}</span></li>
                        <li>age: <span> {person.dob.age}</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <img src={person.picture.large} alt="person face" />

                </div>
    })
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v1yzg6)

Comment: Hi, the result without the [0] does not work because the all the data is stored in objects in the first array. If you copy paste the url: randomuser.me/api/?results=5 in your browser it will become more clear what I mean I think.

Comment: Check the Demo link.

Comment: Instead of check with length, Use `Array.isArray(this.state.person)` for better practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make two changes..
**1.** Assign all results in state instead of single record.
**2.** Validate and iterate over this.state.person to get all the records.
Your code should be look like below.

```
import React from 'react';

class PersonInfo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: null,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    // assign all results in state instead of single record
    this.setState({ person: data.results, loading: false })
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!this.state.person) {
      return <div>didn't get a person</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="person-container">
        {/* validate and iterate over this.state.person to get all the records */}
        {Array.isArray(this.state.person) && this.state.person.map(person => {
          return <div className="person-card">
            <div className="person-card-title">
              <h4>{person.name.title} </h4>

              <h4>{person.name.first} </h4>
              <h4>{person.name.last}</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="person-card-info">
              <ul>
                <li>adres: <span> {person.location.street}     </span> <span>{person.location.city}</span></li>
                <li>phone: <span> {person.phone}</span></li>
                <li>age: <span> {person.dob.age}</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <img src={person.picture.large} alt="person face" />
          </div>
        })}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonInfo;
```